# Exception when using taglibs in Glassfish 3.1

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I'm getting the following error while trying to deploy my app in Glasfish 3.1

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for JSP

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 16 in the jsp file: /WEB-INF/jsp/signup/signup.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
string:///signup_jsp.java:233: package org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form does not exist
```

The spring jars are in the lib directory of my webapplication.

I'm using:
Spring 3.1.3
Glassfish 3.1.1 (started using the Maven embedded pluging)

Any ideas?

Comment: Try putting the Jasper and the Spring jars in the `lib` subfolder of the Glassfish domain folder where you deploy the app.

Comment: Thanks for your input @remigio . Any ideas how to make this work?  Can I just add dependencies ? Or do I have manually make maven copy them there?

Comment: This is just a workaround, I had the same issue with Jasper on Glassfish and that was the only way to make it work. I just copied the jars in the lib folder, maybe a maven goal would be safer, but I think it's not just a matter of adding dependencies, you have to configure a task to copy the jars in that folder.

Comment: I gave up on the embedded Glassfish.  My app works from Eclipse to debug, and works in production. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled onto the answer [here](http://javaevangelist.blogspot.com/2013/01/glassfish-3-tip-of-day-using-jdk-7-with.html)

Basically you need this in glassfish-web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
  <class-loader delegate="true"/>
  <jsp-config>
    <property name="keepgenerated" value="true">
      <description>Keep a copy of the generated servlet class' java code.</description>
    </property>
    <property name="compilerSourceVM" value="7"/>
    <property name="compilerTargetVM" value="7"/>
  </jsp-config>
</glassfish-web-app>
```