# getting com.sun.faces.taglib.jsf_core does not exist while trying to run JSF example

Tags: jsf

I am trying to run a sample JSF code but getting following Jasper exception:-

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for JSP

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 14 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
package com.sun.faces.taglib.jsf_core does not exist

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 14 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
package com.sun.faces.taglib.jsf_core does not exist

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 14 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
package com.sun.faces.taglib.jsf_core does not exist

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 15 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
package com.sun.faces.taglib.html_basic does not exist

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 15 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
package com.sun.faces.taglib.html_basic does not exist

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 15 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
package com.sun.faces.taglib.html_basic does not exist
```

I have created the war of the  project and deployed on glassfish. All the required jars are there in the lib folder : jsf-api.jar, jsf-impl.jar, jstl-1.1.0.jar

Following is my index.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="f" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="h" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
  <head><title>Simple jsp page</title></head>
  <body>

  <f:view>
      <h:outputLabel value="Hello, world"/>
  </f:view>

  </body>
</html>
```

Don't know why it is not able find the package. Please provide some pointers.

Thanks,
Parikshit

Comment: Apart from the concrete problem, why are you learning JSF 1.x instead of JSF 2.x? JSF 2.x was introduced december 2009 and JSP was deprecated at that time. Try to focus on freshness of the learning resources and make sure that the versions used in the learning resources match at least the currently available versions.

Comment: Got it! You need to add glassfish-web.xml to your project.
[more on that][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13518557/exception-when-using-taglibs-in-glassfish-3-1

Comment: @BalusC Thanks for the advice! Will try it with xhtml :)